# Symfony2: How to validate locale thats coming from the url

Tags: symfony, locale

I have implemented the locale in my symfony2 project. Now the problem is if i manually change the locale in the url to something other than locale values it is just taking that value. How do i restrict this?

For example: http://myproject.com/en changing to http://myproject.com/asdf .
Now asdf is not a locale value in my config! but still it displays in my locale switcher as Country-asdf!!

How do i restrict url editing of locale?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the route restrictions in your routing . If it is YML ,

```
homepage:
pattern:   /{locale}
defaults:  { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:homepage, locale: en }
requirements:
    culture:  en|fr|in
```